# MSAL include MSGraph

Tags: objective-c, azure, azure-ad-msal

The sample library: ms-identity-macOS-swift-objc
appears to make use of MSGraph without 'importing' an headers from MSGraph.  The only import is 'MSAL'... I don't understand this.  Does MSAL provide access to MSGraph with no further action. I need to read Mailbox settings and create new Contacts.  Do I need to import MSGraph?  Is there relevant documentation I should read?

Thanks for any thoughts here!
Steve

Comment: this library which is written in Swift initializes webViewParameters= MSALWebviewParameters(). so in Objc webViewParamaters = [[MSALWebviewParameters alloc] init];  but I get: Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.WebAuthenticationSession Code=2 "Cannot start ASWebAuthenticationSession without providing presentation context. Set presentationContextProvider before calling -start."   How do I set this presentationContext in ObjC?  Why don't I see this error in the supplied library?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are searching for - Microsoft Graph SDK for ObjC:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-objc

Each network call to Microsoft Graph needs to be authenticated. For that purpose, creation of an instance of MSHTTPClient takes an MSAuthenticationProvider protocol's instance as parameter.

You can create the MSAuthenticationProvider instance via two ways:

Using MSGraphMSALAuthProvider
This repo handles the authentication scenarios via MSAL - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-objc-auth

By writing your own implmentation of MSAuthenticationProvider

Comment: Thanks for trying but you don't answer either of the original two questions...  The MSGraphMSALAuthProvider mentioned does not support macOS (for nearly 2 years now!). Since you seem knowledgeable want to try to answer the updated question which shows error in MSAL?